# Eclipse Web Project Name

Tags: java, eclipse, web

I have 2 web projects and 2 framework projects in my Eclipse workspace.  I copied one project to another and changed names in the .project file. All code and JSP pages compile fine.  When I go to the Add/Remove dialog of my Tomcat eclipse server the new web project shows up named properlyy but in parenthesis it has the original project name.  This is true of the new framework project also.  Does anyone know where I need to change the name.

Comment: I would just re-create workspace

Answer (score 3):

Found it.

.settings\org.eclipse.wst.common.component