# Copied project in parentheses - tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, copy

I copied a project with another name (copy-paste). When I run it, I see the copied project in parentheses. How can I remove it?

Another person has the same problem ([Eclipse Web Project Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24663574/eclipse-web-project-name)) but I can´t find `.settings\org.eclipse.wst.common.component`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your *workspace location*, open your *project folder*.

You should see a folder named ***".settings"***, inside it is the file ***"org.eclipse.wst.common.component"***